# MessageQueue.Exists returns true for one site, false for another!

Tags: message-queue

I have two websites running on the same IIS instance on the same 2008 R2 server, both sharing a common messaging assembly that attempts to log messages to a messagequeue on the server. They're both calling the same method, which in turn calls

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Exists(QueueName);
```

Where QueueName is the correct (and 100% painstakingly verified) queue name.
Both sites pass in the same string, but site A returns true for the above statement, while site B returns false!
For this reason I'm assuming it's a .net or IIS setting somewhere, but I don’t really know what settings within the given site would affect this.

As I say, I've checked the input string in both methods and its 100% identical. They’re both running on the same server, configured for the same version of the .net framework.
Can anyone suggest anything that could make a standard .net framework call like this produce different results?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea as to the underlying cause, but ininstalling and reinstalling message queuing on the server seems to have resolved the problem Frustrating, as Id rather get to the bottom of the cause, but there we go.